# How does disabling interrupts solve the critical section problem?

Tags: assembly, concurrency, kernel, interrupt

I'm going through some lecture notes with code like this and don't really understand why disabling interrupts solves the concurrency problem. If there are 2 threads running, the first one calls CLI() to disable interrupts, then enters the critical section. How does this stop the second thread from calling increment(x), calling CLI(), then also entering the critical section?

There seems to be some gap in my understanding - is it that an interrupt is required for the second thread to run? When would the CPU switch to running a different thread?

```
void increment(int &x) {
    CLI();

    // critical section
    int temp = x;
    temp = temp + 1;
    x = temp;

    STI(); 
}
```

Comment: Given that there is only one processor present, or the threads are always running on the same processor, then indeed an interrupt is needed to switch from the execution context of one thread to the other. A true `cli` instruction in ring 0 will avoid the possibility of another thread running. (NMIs can still occur but the OS can insure to never switch thread contexts from an NMI.) This is not sufficient if multiprocessing is used however.